# Finding Worst Case complexity of the function 4n log n+7n

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am having a hard time trying to solve this one particular Big Oh problem:

```
4n log n+7n=O(n log n)
```

I have tried by applying n>=1, but nothing's coming out of it and the only hint is that 4n log n dominates 7n.

Comment: Check Wikipedia and find the mathematical definition of what Big-O of a function (IE: `O(f(n))`) actually means.  The definition will yield the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below approach:

```
4n log n + 7n <= 4n log n + 7n log n ; for all n>=2
              <= 11n log n
              = O(n log n).
```

Hence, you can say that n log n dominates in this function, and the worst complexity comes out to be `O(n log n)`.